# d3-force: keep graph compact when filtering/removing nodes

Tags: d3.js

I use `d3-force` to lay out a graph with about 360 nodes.

```
const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
    .force(
        'charge',
        d3.forceManyBody()
            .distanceMax(200)
            .strength(-50)
    )
    .force(
        'link',
        d3.forceLink(links)
            .id((d) => d.id)
            .distance(30)
    )
    .force(
        'center',
        d3.forceCenter(
            $svg.innerWidth() / 2,
            $svg.innerHeight() / 2,
        )
    );
```

[image]

this looks good with all nodes visible – but there will also be the possibility to filter/remove nodes, in which case I would want the graph to be way more *compact* than it actually is (see animation).

this is probably due to the fact that there are no edges between the remaining nodes, and the fact that they are already spread out a lot when the new simulation starts.

while I could simply reset all node positions to the center of the canvas, that would not look great transition-wise. ideally each node would move from its current position to its new position in a more compact layout.

is there a way to achieve this?

I thought maybe the `forceManyBody` strength could transition from a positive value (attraction) at first to a negative value (repulsion), but apparently this value is can only be set once for the run of the simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding an attraction force (https://github.com/ericsoco/d3-force-attract) works well enough.